# mount vmfs partition in esxi

Tags: vmware-esxi, iscsi, datastore, vmfs

I lost connection to an iSCSI disk, and after reconnecting the datastore has not mounted. I can see the VMFS partition, but I'm not sure how to mount it manually. The UI options don't seem to offer an option. I can create a new datastore, but only by deleting the current one.

[image]

the `esxcfg-volume -l` command outputs the following:

```
Scanning for VMFS-6 host activity (4096 bytes/HB, 1024 HBs).
VMFS UUID/label: 5e125199-81833a30-7767-a0369f07542d/mynas2
Can mount: Yes
Can resignature: Yes
Extent name: naa.60014055ecf517ed409fd40c2d8b6ad5:1 range: 0 - 409343 (MB)
```

`partedUtil getptbl /vmfs/devices/disk/naa.60014055ecf517ed409fd40c2d8b6ad5`

displays the following

```
gpt
52216 255 63 838860800
1 2048 838858752 AA31E02A400F11DB9590000C2911D1B8 vmfs 0
```

and `vmfstools -V` generates the following output in `/var/log/vmkernel.log`

```
2020-01-14T06:03:33.259Z cpu4:2099636)WARNING: NFS: 1227: Invalid volume UUID snap-4738e717-5e125199-5197aa88-8da9-a0369f07542d
2020-01-14T06:03:33.276Z cpu4:2099636)HBX: 1034: 'mynas2': HB at offset 3637248 - Setting pulse failed: Not supported:
2020-01-14T06:03:33.276Z cpu4:2099636)  [HB state abcdef02 offset 3637248 gen 27 stampUS 1257591573 uuid 5e1d54ef-e63704a9-378c-a0369f07542d jrnl <FB 0> drv 24.82 lockImpl 4 ip 10.4.1.11]
2020-01-14T06:03:33.276Z cpu4:2099636)WARNING: FSAts: 1550: Denying reservation access on an ATS-only vol 'mynas2'
2020-01-14T06:03:33.276Z cpu4:2099636)WARNING: HBX: 2423: ATS-Only VMFS volume 'mynas2' is not mounted. This host does not support ATS, or ATS initialization failed.
2020-01-14T06:03:33.276Z cpu4:2099636)WARNING: HBX: 2437: Failed to initialize VMFS distributed locking on volume 5e125199-81833a30-7767-a0369f07542d: Not supported
2020-01-14T06:03:33.333Z cpu1:2099636)FSS: 6092: No FS driver claimed device 'snap-4738e717-5e125199-5197aa88-8da9-a0369f07542d': No filesystem on the device
2020-01-14T06:03:33.333Z cpu7:2099797)VC: 4616: Device rescan time 7 msec (total number of devices 4)
2020-01-14T06:03:33.333Z cpu7:2099797)VC: 4619: Filesystem probe time 131 msec (devices probed 4 of 4)
2020-01-14T06:03:33.333Z cpu7:2099797)VC: 4621: Refresh open volume time 0 msec
```

answer: [VM Inaccessible](https://serverfault.com/questions/784375/vm-inaccessible/784407#784407)

Answer (score 4):

obtain the UUID of VMFS partition using

```
esxcli storage vmfs snapshot list
```

then mount it using

```
esxcli storage vmfs snapshot mount -u <UUID>
```

Comment: Thanks, this saved me a bunch of problems when trying to migrate an iscsi volume on TrueNAS, where only one of the two datastore where visible on ESXi.